# Fedora Crontab Changes

Tags: linux, fedora, centos, cron

When I make a change to the /etc/crontab file, what service do I need to reload/restart in order for the changes to take effect?

```
service crond restart
```

doesn't work. "crond: unrecognized service"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have crond (vixie-cron) installed.
If you type `which crond` and not get /usr/sbin/crond, then you need to run `yum install vixie-cron`.

Comment: Does this mean I have no crons running on the server........? Isn't that like.. bad?